# Changing edge color based on attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I'm working on the visual representation of a network on R software, using the `igraph` package.

I have a data set with links between all the nodes and, for each link/edge, the district that they are assign to.

So, I would like to change the edge color of each edge, based on each district they are assign to. The table above shows the structure of the table.

| nodei | nodej | depot1 | depot2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 |

In this case the link (4-5) is assigned to depot1, so the edge color of the edge should be green, for example.

Comment: please share a reproducible example/data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exmaple that edges associated with `1` will be colored in "red", and "green" otherwise:

```
g <- make_ring(5)
g %>%
  set_edge_attr(
    name = "color",
    value = c("green", "red")[1 + (rowSums(ends(., E(.)) == "1") > 0)]
  ) %>%
  plot()
```

In your case, you could replace `"1"` by `"depot1"` and have a try.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question, I created a `node type` to color the edges and nodes.

```
library(igraph)

data <- read.table(text = "
N     D  type
1     6 A
3     7 B
7     8 A
4     5 B
7    10 A
4     6 B
1     7 A
6     8 B
7     9 B
6     10 A ", header=T )

nodes <- data.frame(id=unique(c(data$N, data$D)) )
nodes$type <- c("A","B") # this if for the layout
nodes$x <- c(1,3,7,4,7, 4,  1,6,7,6) 
nodes$y <- c(6,7,8,5,10,,5, 7,8,9,10)
nodes
                 
G <- graph_from_data_frame(dd, vertices = nodes ) 

V(G)$color <- ifelse( V(G)$type == "A",  "red", "green")
E(G)$color <- ifelse( E(G)$type == "A", "red","green")

edge_attr(G)
vertex_attr(G)
plot(G)
```

[image]